# jquery bug with firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug, mozilla

I am using jQuery javascript framework and whenever i load pages with firebug it returns "$" as an anonymous() function in console. Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eh? I just popped open my firebug on this page, typed $ into the console and it said `function()`. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Do reload your page with firebug opened and hit $ into console you will see $ as anonymous() function.

Comment: The problem is actually exactly as he describes. Under certain circumstances, it does this. Yes, it is because firebug does not have jquery loaded. When this happens, the normal js environment does have jq loaded, it's just firebug that can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jQuery was not loaded when you tried to call it. Try calling the object using `jQuery` instead of `$` to confirm jQuery was actually loaded. Also, are you using other libraries like Prototype as well because they might be interfering with the $ object!! If yes, try using `jQuery.noConflict()`.

Comment: Well, that does solves the problem if prototype and jquery is used but I am not using prototype. I tried to call only after page was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know *why* it happens, but yes I see it often too. Something about firebug interferes with the binding of the jQuery function to $ under some circumstance. 
You're probably aware it's just the firebug console that's bugging out ( $() in included scripts should be working as expected), but it's worth mentioning. Usually I have to reload the page, or even kill the tab.

I'd like to understand why it happens, but for now when it happens (assuming jquery really is loaded in the page) I found I can fix it in the console with:

```
$ = jQuery;
```